# Simple Form - Custom Input Not Being Recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

So I'm wanting to have a custom input component defined for a simple form and have the following:

```
# app/inputs/gds_input.rb
class GdsInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input(wrapper_options = nil)
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

And then in a form I have the following:

```
<%= builder.simple_fields_for :registration, registration do |reg| %>
  <fieldset>
    <%= reg.input :first_name, required: true, input_html: { maxlength: 40, class: 'gds-Input' }, as: :gds_input %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

However I'm getting a `No input found for gds_input` error at RunTime.

Any thoughts as to that for which I had not accounted?

Comment: try using `as: :gds` instead

Comment: worked like a charm! thanks @MrYoshiji! If you want to add as an answer, I'll accept it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom class must have a suffix `Input`, and to use it you must remove that suffix from the `underscore` version of that class name.

---

In your case:

```
# class name is GdsInput
reg.input :first_name, {...}, as: :gds
```